# Using Green's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a Green's domain with boundary $\Gamma$. For functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ that are twice continuously differentiable on an open set containing $\Omega \cup \Gamma$, show that

$$ \int_\Gamma \bigg( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx + u \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy \bigg) = \int \int_\Omega det\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix} dx dy $$

Answer (score 1):

Green's theorem states
$$
\int_\Gamma P \, dx + Q \, dy = \iint_\Omega \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \, dA.
$$
It should be clear what to use for $P$ and $Q$.